# Who came up with R for the universal gas constant?

Tags: terminology, naming-conventions

I never did find an answer from professors, or even see an acknowledgement in textbooks, on why capital-letter-r is invariably used to represent the constant 0.08206 L-atm/mol-K seen in chemistry everywhere. The only variation I've seen is to use subscripts or overbars to denote incorporation of a particular circumstances.

Comment: Try this http://www.che.uc.edu/jensen/W.%20B.%20Jensen/Reprints/100.%20Gas%20Constant.pdf "Why is the universal gas constant in *PV = nRT* represented by the letter *R*?"  His answer: Clapeyron first used this, and proposes possible reasons why.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Perhaps you could convert this into an answer, with the quote about the ratio and Regnault ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quote from [*Ask the Historian*](http://www.che.uc.edu/jensen/W.%20B.%20Jensen/Reprints/100.%20Gas%20Constant.pdf) "The Universal Gas Constant" by William B. Jensen, Department of Chemistry, University of Cincinnati, published in *J. Chem. Educ.*, **2003**, *80, 731-732*

> **Question**
>   Why is the universal gas constant in $PV = nRT$ represented by the letter $R$?
>   **Answer**
>   This is best answered by tracing the origins of the ideal gas law itself. One of the first persons to combine Boyle’s law (1662) relating volume and pressure and Gay-Lussac’s law (1802) relating volume and temperature in a single equation appears to have been the French engineer, Benoit-Paul Emile Clapeyron (1799- 1864). In his famous memoir of 1834 on the Carnot cycle, he wrote the combined equation as 
>   $$
> pv = R(267 + t) \tag{1}$$
>   where $t$ is the temperature in degrees centigrade.

Later versions of the law kept the letter $R$.

Later in the same reference, Jensen guesses why "$R$" was chosen by Clapeyron.

> So why did Clapeyron choose the letter $R$ for the constant in his gas law? The fact is that he doesn’t explicitly tell us why and we are left with two speculative answers: (a) it was arbitrary or (b) it stood for *ratio* or one of its French equivalents: *raison* or *rapport*, since Clapeyron noted that the value of R for each gas was obtained by evaluating the constancy of the ratio $pv/(267 + t)$ over a range of pressures and temperatures, a point also emphasized by Clausius using the revised ratio $pv/(273 + t)$.

Comment: Exasperating, but I can't force him (Clapeyron) to change now.